# Relative clauses: where vs. which

Tags: word-choice, relative-clauses

In the sentence below, can I change *which* to *where*?

> We often go to visit our friends in Bristol, **which** is not very far away.

Comment: What does your research into the possibilities show?

Comment: No, they are not interchangeable in your example. Note that you can say "We often visit Bristol, where we have friends".

Comment: The _it_ should not be there anyway. _Bristol, which is not far away._ is correct, _*Bristol, where (it) is not far away_ makes little sense.

Comment: **which** is a relative pronoun. **where** is a relative adverb. You will find more information about relative adverbs here. http://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-relative-adverbs/2944081.html

Comment: @JavaLatte *Where* is not an adverb. It's a preposition.

Comment: @Araucaria: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/where, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where

Comment: @JavaLatte Ah, you committed a rookie error! [Never use dictionaries for parts of speech! It's not what they're there for!](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-word-parts/6635#6635) :-)

Comment: @JavaLatte Btw, I love your scuba diving pun. It's great.

Comment: @Araucaria: we aim to please. Can you point me to any online references that demonstrate that  **where** is a preposition?

Comment: @JavaLatteYou could [read the notes here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adv_place.html), but I'll try and find you something better ...

Comment: @JavaLatte You can see *here* and *there* listed in example [12] on page 133 [here, in this chapter on prepositions](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar). *Where* is a member of this trio of locative prepositions.

Comment: @JavaLatte You could have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221110/word-classes-in-specific-sentence). I'll try to find something more definitive and useful tomorrow some time.

Answer (score 1):

> We often go to visit our friends in Bristol, ***which*** is not very far away.

Can I change ***which*** to ***where***? No, here we can't change.

> We often go to visit our friends in Bristol, ***which*** is not very far away.

This sentence means that *we often go to visit our friends in Bristol, and Bristol is not very far away*.

The relativizer - *where* - doesn't function like the way relativizer - *which* - functions. Consider the following sentence -

> We often go to visit Bristol, ***where*** our friends live.

*we often go to visit Bristol*. and *our friends lives [in Bristol]*. You see *where* replaces that *in* along with the antecedent *Bristol*. But if we had to use *which* in place of *where* we would have had to retain that *in* in our sentence to make it grammatical.

> We often go to visit Bristol, ***which*** our friends live in.

or

> We often go to visit Bristol, in ***which*** our friends live.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use where. If you were to use "where", you should change the sentence structure. Maybe like this: We often go to visit our friends' house in Bristol, which is not very far away.

Comment: Your suggested change doesn't use "where" nor is it possible with yours to use where in place of which